# Crash When Cerr'ing A Variable From A Tuple

Tags: c++, c++11, stdtuple

For some reason when I try to `std::cerr` a variable in an `std::tuple`, my program crashes. My guess is that `std::get<int>( std::tuple )` is returning garbledy-gook. Is there any reason why the values passed into an `std::tuple` would change, at all (upon passing in, or upon a call to std::get< int >( std::tuple ), because of some strange wording in the standard, or a faulty implementation)? e.g from a copy, something silly happens when you try to read one (i.e `std::get`), etc.?

EDIT: This question is meant to be abstract, and is not necessarily about the code below, but to provide information on std::tuple, I (and others who read this post) may be able to use in the future.

UPDATE: Works from MinGW GCC 4.4.1 as well.

UPDATE:
I just noticed my code runs on ideone.com:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <tuple>
#include <typeinfo>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

template< int IETORATOR_T, typename TUPLE, typename FUNCTION_POINTER_T, typename... ARGUMENTS_T >
struct FunctionRunner
{
    FunctionRunner( TUPLE* tuple, FUNCTION_POINTER_T functionToRun, ARGUMENTS_T... arguments )
    {
        std::cerr << "Hi there!\n";
        //TEST CODE.//
        ///////////////////////////////////////////
        /////I can read from the value.//
        auto j = std::forward< decltype( std::get< IETORATOR_T >( *tuple ) ) >( std::get< IETORATOR_T >( *tuple ) );
        //I can write to the value.//
        j += 2;
        std::cerr << "------------\n";
        //I cant cerr the value? 0.0//
        std::cerr << "Passing " << j << "\n";
        FunctionRunner< IETORATOR_T - 1, TUPLE, FUNCTION_POINTER_T, decltype( std::get< IETORATOR_T >( *tuple ) ), ARGUMENTS_T... > runner{ 
                tuple, functionToRun, std::get< IETORATOR_T >( *tuple ), arguments... };
    }
};
template< typename TUPLE, typename FUNCTION_POINTER_T, typename... ARGUMENTS_T >
struct FunctionRunner< ( -1 ), TUPLE, FUNCTION_POINTER_T, ARGUMENTS_T... >
{
    FunctionRunner( TUPLE* tuple, FUNCTION_POINTER_T functionToRun, ARGUMENTS_T... arguments ) {
        functionToRun( arguments... );
    }
};

template< typename... ARGUMENT_TYPES_T >
struct ArgumentMaker
{
    std::tuple< ARGUMENT_TYPES_T... >* argumentData;
    ArgumentMaker( ARGUMENT_TYPES_T... arguments ) {
        argumentData = new std::tuple< ARGUMENT_TYPES_T... >( std::forward< ARGUMENT_TYPES_T >( arguments )... );
    }
    ~ArgumentMaker() {
        delete argumentData;
    }
    template< typename FUNCTION_POINTER_T >
    void ExecuteFunction( FUNCTION_POINTER_T functionToRun ) {
        FunctionRunner< ( std::tuple_size< std::tuple< ARGUMENT_TYPES_T... > >::value - 1 ), 
                std::tuple< ARGUMENT_TYPES_T... >, FUNCTION_POINTER_T > runner{ argumentData, functionToRun };
    }
};

void Test( int a, double d, float c ) {
    std::cerr << a << " " << d << " " << c << "\n";
}

int main()
{
    int a = 2;
    double b = 34.5;
    float c = 45.6f;
    auto* maker = new ArgumentMaker< int, double, float >( a, b, c );
    maker->ExecuteFunction( &Test );
    delete maker;
    return ( 0 );
}
```

The compiler I am using on my desktop is MinGW's GCC 4.8.1-4. Is this a compiler bug?

Comment: How about showing some code, preferably in the form of a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org)?

Comment: @DanielFrey I did post the code. It is a bit long (for this particular instance it is a bit hard for it not to be), and the question is meant to be abstract, I am not looking for help with my problem at the moment, rather information I can reference in the future.

Comment: Why does that code use `new` and `delete`?  Nothing there requires dynamic allocation

Comment: @JonathanWakely I was just trying to eliminate any possibility of anything getting copied for testing purposes.

Comment: You should **simplify** code for testing purposes, not complicate it. What is your use of `forward` meant to do? `tuple_element` would be simpler than that `decltype`, but I'd get rid of the `forward` entirely. Finally, I am positive the problem is your code, not a compiler bug.

Comment: @JonathanWakely Again, std::forward was put there, for testing purposes, to eliminate the possibility of a variable getting passed in incorrectly (I have removed, it and put it back several times). This code is not production. It is something I am just hacking together to test stuff. The reason I suggested a compiler bug is: the code does not work with one compiler, but works with another, although like you said, it could just be because it is crappy code :-/.

Comment: Are you able to write other things to `cerr`? There is no way writing any `int`, `double` or `float` to `cerr` should crash, so even if `std::get` could return the wrong value, it wouldn't cause a crash. The answer to your abstract question is "no, there is no way values in a tuple magically change, don't be silly" (and such abstract questions are off topic here.)

Comment: @TheFloatingBrain: The code you posted shouldn't crash, try a clean and rebuild and make sure the code you posted is the same.

Comment: @JesseGood Thanks for the suggestion, I was actually working from the command line though. I just changed my g++ environment variable to point to 4.4.1 instead of 4.8.1-4, and it worked 0.0. I did update this post with any changes well.

Comment: @JonathanWakely Thank you for the reply/answer. I was just using cerr as a test-case, but, actually, I just tested it, I cant write any non-constants to cerr with 4.8.1-4, if I compile with 4.4.1 it works. I only installed 4.8.1-4 yesterday.The question does sound a little silly as worded, I probalby should have phrased it: "upon passing a value to a std::tuple's constructor, or upon the retaining of a value with std::get, is there any wording in the standard, with respect to either of the mentioned (or anything implementation specific about std::tuple), regarding modifications to the data."

Comment: @JonathanWakely Also, if you want to post your answer, I will mark it as the answer, and +1 it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any reason why the values passed into an `std::tuple` would change, at all?

No, of course not, unless you change them.  A `std::tuple` is just a structure that holds values as members, it doesn't have any magical properties that cause values to update silently.

You should simplify your code to something *really* basic instead of all that irrelevant clutter and see if that works:

```
#include <tuple>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::tuple<int> t{ 1 };
    std::cerr << std::get<0>(t);
}
```

If that doesn't work, make it even simpler:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int t = 1 ;
    std::cerr << t;
}
```

If that doesn't work something is very broken in your MinGW installation, but it's nothing to do with `tuple` or variadic templates or dynamic allocation or anything else in your original code.